# Getting the values of elements that have been dropped on eachother with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".element").draggable();
    $(".element").droppable({
        drop: function () {
            alert('dropped');
        }
    });
});
```

Anything with the class of 'element' can be manipulated and dragged around the page. I want to be able to find the HTML contents of the element that is being dragged and the element that is being dropped and use them where "alert('dropped');" is, so I could do something like:

```
alert(firstelement+ ' was dropped on ' +secondelement);
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: you want to alert per one or, alert after a certain number has been dropped?

Comment: After any item is dropped on another, the alert triggers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add parameters to your drop callback.

```
drop : function(event, ui) {
   var droppable = $(this);
   var draggable = ui.draggable;

   alert(droppable.attr('id') + " was dropped on " + draggable.attr('id'));
}
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop